# Delete method being called too many times. Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app allows you to long press on an item, and then select delete as an option. When you press delete an alert view pops up and asks you to confirm that you want to delete it. When I select yes it deletes TWO items, not just one. Using breakpoints I know it is cycling through the method multiple times. Twice to be exact

Here is the code

```
- (void)delete:(id)sender
{
MYSDynamicAlertView *alertView = [MYSDynamicAlertView new];

alertView.alertTitle = @"Are you sure you want to delete that?";
alertView.message = @"You won't be able to retrieve the message once its deleted.";

[alertView setTitle:@"Delete" dismissBlock:^{
    FCIMessageCell *cell               = self.cellShowingMenuController;
    NSIndexPath *ip                    = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    FHChatInteraction *chatInteraction = self.visitor.chatInteractions[ip.row];
    [[FHSChatSocket sharedSocket] sendDeleteChatInteraction:chatInteraction];
    [chatInteraction destroy];    }
          direction:MYSDynamicAlertViewDirectionUp];

[alertView setTitle:@"Cancel" dismissBlock:^{
} direction:MYSDynamicAlertViewDirectionDown];


[alertView show];

}
```

So how to I fix this? Why is it calling it twice, instead of once?

Comment: is it really hitting [alertView show]; twice?

Comment: or is it only hitting [[FHSChatSocket sharedSocket] sendDeleteChatInteraction:chatInteraction]; twice?

Comment: Who calls it two times? You can see that in the stack trace. Please post both traces.

Comment: only hits `[alertView show];` once. Here is a video http://d.pr/v/w24y

Comment: @Daij-Djan does the video help?

Comment: what ricardo said is what I wanted to test ;) I was too lazy too fix it though :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug in `MYSDynamicAlertView` which causes the block to be called twice. I just fixed it and submitted a pull request.

In the meantime you can find the fixed code [here](https://github.com/rsanchezsaez/MYSDynamicAlertView/tree/bugfix).

Comment: great thanks what I needed to know. Would you mind closing the pull request and I'll go through the code?

Comment: What do you mean by closing the pull request? I actually do want to MYSDynamicAlertView merge my changes (or fix the issue). You can download my code without me doing anything to the pull request.

Comment: Thanks I'm teaching myself objective-c so I'll go through and see if I can fix it now that you pointed out the issue

Comment: Ok! Didn't realize you are a member of the MYSDynamicAlertView repo.

Comment: Yep! Haha until now I didn't know people could see MYSDynamicAlertView repo.. you kind of surprised me. Thanks for the help this is awesome

Comment: It's a very nice widget this MYSDynamicAlertView! Cool effect. MYSGravityActionSheet is also cool. Props to Mysterious Trousers for sharing. ;-)